copy 1d char* array as a row into 2d char* array (memcpy C behaviour in loop)
in the code below, I want to be able to input using stdin bash commands separated by new lines, and execute them sequentially using forks and execvp. right now, my code takes the line, tokenises it (for argument's sake) and then appends it to a char* array called cmd. I then want to add this to cmdList as a row. However, every time I try with memcpy, it doesn't output my expected behaviour, and I was hoping that someone could help explain and point me in the right direction thanks. Full codebase is below. currently as it is, I am testing using ./sequence < cmdfile, where command file contains these lines. sequence.c currently outputs only the date.
cmdfile
whoami
cal 4 2020
echo The time is:
date

sequence.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#define MAX_ARGS 10
#define MAX_LINE 256
#define MAX_COMMANDS 100

int main() {
    int cmdSize;
    char line[MAX_LINE];
    char* cmdList[MAX_COMMANDS][MAX_ARGS + 1];
//read 100 lines
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_COMMANDS; i++) {
    cmdSize = 0; //reset cmdSize every iter
    fgets(line, MAX_LINE, stdin); //read line from stdin
    if(line[0] == 10) {
        break;
    }
    line[strcspn(line,"\n")] = 0; //strip \n from back of lines so that the commands are clean
    char* token = strtok(line, " ");
    char* cmd[11] = {};
    while(token) {
        cmd[cmdSize] = token;
        //cmdList[i][cmdSize] = token;

        cmdSize++;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }//tokenise and add to cmd arr
    memcpy(cmdList[i], cmd, sizeof(cmd));
}
printf("%s, ", cmdList[0][0]);
printf("%s, ", cmdList[1][0]);
printf("%s, ", cmdList[2][0]);
//start of forks, broken right now
for (int i = 0; i<cmdSize; i++) {
    
    //forks
    int fid;
    fid = fork();
    if (fid < 0) {
    perror("fork error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (fid == 0) {
        execvp(cmdList[i][0], cmdList[i]); //execute on child
        perror("Exec error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        wait(NULL); // wait until child is finished
    }
}
return 0;
}

tried appending to the 2d array using a loop, did not work, same behaviour

Please provide a [mre] (ideally with hardcoded input) to demonstrate what you observe, but also describe what exactly you do observe and what exactly you do expect and explicitly what difference you see. Try for [ask] and consider taking the [tour] please.

Don't use magic numbers. If by the value 10 in line[0] == 10 mean the ASCII value for newline, use the actual characters '\n' instead.

The problem is that all the calls to strtok will always give you pointers into the one single line array.
And each iteration of the outer for loop will "reset" the contents of the line array, so all the pointers you store in cmdList will be to different places in the line array which will always have the contents of the last successful call to fgets
You need to to actually copy the strings, and not the pointers. Or use dynamic allocation with e.g. strdup (or your own implementation if your system doesn't have it).

cmd[cmdSize] = token;

is a shallow copy. It only copies the pointers, and not the underlying data. You need to actually copy the underlying data, else you'd end up with all the pointers pointing inside a single line array, which will have the contents of the most recent fgets() call.
As you're already assuming POSIX support, it is simple:
cmd[cmdSize] = strdup(token);

if (!cmd[cmdSize]) {
    /* Memory allocation failed. Handle error here. */
}

Also note that char* cmd[11] = {}; is not valid before C2X, unless you're using GNU extensions.
And instead of comparing the ASCII code, use the actual character:
#if 0
if(line[0] == 10) {
    break;
}
#else
if (line[0] == '\n') {
    break;
}


Hi, using c99 it compiles. However if char* cmd[11] = {}; is not valid, what would an alternative be? Thank you in advance!

Did you compile with std=c99 -pedantic-errors? The alternative is char *cmd[11] = {0}.

For me, GCC outputs: "error: ISO C forbids empty initializer braces before C2X."
